# Is there any way to know if the lines on the canvas (Path) are overlapping?

Tags: flutter, dart, canvas, path

I would like to know if there is any logic or function to get a **bool** when two lines overlap, I tried to do it myself with for cycles of each `List<Offset>`, however each **Offset** is not exact, because depending on how you draw it, you put a point and then add the line, something like that is my code to draw :

[image]

```
void _drawFromPointList(Canvas canvas, DrawnShape currentShape) {
    final Path path = Path();
    final pointList = currentShape.pointList;

    /// starts at first point
    path.moveTo(
      pointList[0].dx,
      pointList[0].dy,
    );

    /// goes through every point of the line, (starts at 1)
    for (int f = 1; f < pointList.length; f++) {
      path.lineTo(pointList[f].dx, pointList[f].dy);
    }


    /// draw the line
    canvas.drawPath(path, currentShape.paint);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Path.combine()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Path/combine.html) to achieve that.

Should be something along the lines of:

```
final intersection = Path.combine(PathOperation.intersect, path1, path2);
final pathsAreIntersecting = !intersection.getBounds().isEmpty;
```

Comment: Pardon, that was written from the top of my head. The [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Rect-class.html) says that `isEmpty` does exist instead. You can take the negation of that. I will update my answer

Comment: I tried with `isEmpty` but always is `true`, even passing over the other path (as I made a static one for testing) :c

Comment: Now i have `false`, firstly, it sais `true` but when i pass to the path static says `false true false true`, and when i create another draw (not yet passing over the static path) says  `false true false true`. I update my answer

Comment: Maybe you should ask a separate question for that, so that more people see it again. Your edit is very huge and kinda dilutes the original question.
I would mark this answer as accepted, remove your edit and ask a new question instead.

Comment: I follow your advice and now i did another issue here : Thx https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73483392/how-to-take-into-account-the-strokewidth-of-a-paint-to-obtain-an-intersect-bet